# Use socket.io with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

How do I use socket.io with React? I have this code for my client:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import io from "socket.io-client"
import "./App.css"

const socket = io()
console.log(socket)

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // ...
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

And for my server:

```
const express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require("http").Server(app),
    io = require("socket.io")(http)

io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New connection")
})

http.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Started!")
})
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MdZyD8L 404 (Not Found)
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

PS: To launch the app, I do `npm run start`, and for the server `node server/server.js`

Comment: Change on client `const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
console.log(socket);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

havn't really ran the code; but, did you notice the port in the error is **3000** rather than **8000** which you initialized the server to listen on?

reading https://socket.io/docs/client-api/, it says that the default is the window location, knowing react, you probably running on port 3000, which is the same 3000 in the error

try setting the port when initializing the socket object

```
const socket = io("localhost:8000");
```

Comment: Also. be sure to not hardcode it to localhost:8000 when deploying (if doing so) it. I had this and I deployed my app to heroku.. I then found out that there were no connections to my server... because i had it hardcode it to localhost from the client... if you just do io() it will "autoconnect to the window's location" https://socket.io/docs/client-api/

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for connecting through socket if you want that after page is rendered then your socket get connected then write it in componentDidMount.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import io from "socket.io-client"
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

componentDidMount(){
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");
   console.log(socket)
}
    render() {
        return (
            // ...
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

For example you can go through the link : 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-realtime-app-using-socket-io-react-node-mongodb-a10c4a1ab676